# on click function does not work on elements appended with ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

```
 $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $('.box').on("click", function() {
      alert('hello')
    });
  });
```

This does not work on elements with class box that are appended with ajax. It only works on the elements that are present on the initial loading of the page. I have also tried as wrappers:

```
$(document).ready(function() { });
```

and

```
var helloscript = function() { };
```

but nothing works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may call it like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.box', function (event) {

});
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use correct **event delegation** for dinamically added elements:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.box', function() {
   alert('hello')
 });
```

You can read more about event delegation **[here](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**.